# mongodb read and write impossible on remote base

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a projet using Node.js and mongooseJS to acces database.
All my read and write functions work fine when using a local base, but when I switch to a base on a remote server, with the exact same databases and collections, the application does not do anything and I get a timeout.

Since I am very new to mongoDB, is there something I have missed?

Thanks for any advice.

Gabriel

Comment: is there any other info within this exception? did you check network name/ipaddress?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had checked, it was OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you set bindIp in mongodb [configuration file](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#configuration-file).

Also, notice the mongodb version and platform you used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The bind_ip was set to 0.0.0.0 as it should (if I undestood correctly), so the error did not come from there.

The cause was actually that I didn't use the correct database as authenticationDatabase.

Thank anyway.